# Checking whether $\int_D f^2 dA = 0$ over a bounded set in $R^2$ implies $f \equiv 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Working on the following problem:

> Suppose $g$ is a $C^2$ function that is zero at all points of the boundary of a square $D$ in $R^2$ and such that $\Delta g = 2g$. Show that this is not possible unless $g$ is identically zero, using the following integral which holds for $C^2$ functions which go to zero at the boundary:
>
> $\int_D (\Delta g) g dA = - \int_D |\nabla g|^2 dA$.

My proof is to note that with the given assumptions, we have

$2\int_D g^2 dA = -\int_D |\nabla g|^2 dA$.

The right hand side is nonpositive and the left hand side is nonnegative, therefore this can only hold true if both sides of the equation evaluate to 0. Finally, I note that since $g$ is $C^2$ (and therefore continuous), the left hand side implies that $g$ itself must be identically zero. Otherwise there is a small ball $B \subset D$ inside which $g^2$ is strictly positive. Using monotonicity of integration for positive functions, we have

$\int_D g^2 dA \geq \int_B g^2 dA > 0$,

which is a contradiction.

So I looked up the solution and their approach is more longwinded.

The text solution says that since $\int_D |\nabla g|^2 dA = 0$ , we have $\nabla g = 0$ on $D$ (basically for the same reason as in my solution above). Then they say that this implies that $g$ is a constant on $D$, and since $g = 0$ on the boundary, the constant that $g$ is equal to must be zero.

I understand the text solution. But my question is, is it necessary to take this roundabout talking about $\nabla g$ instead of just assessing the left-hand side directly like I did? I am already explicitly using that $g = 0$ at the boundary because I am using the given integral identity. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your proof is correct. There may be some reason the text chooses to argue concerning $\nabla g$ instead - perhaps to warm you up to similar situations where examining $\nabla g$ is required. Or maybe the author just had blinders on when he wrote this problem.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!